# ExpressJS + JWT. What's the proper way to get auth data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, jwt

Let's jump to an example. I'll skip some parts like imports, exports.

I have a controller called controllers/book.js with one route:

```
router.get('/my-books', function(req, res) {
    if(Auth.authenticated(req,res)) {
        Book.getMyBooks(function(rows) {
            response.operationSucceed(req, res, rows);
        });
    }
});
```

Then, in a model called models/book.js I have that function:

```
function getMyBooks(successCallback) {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM book b WHERE b.id_user=?', [Auth.getLoggedUID()], function(rows) {
        successCallback(rows);
    });
}
```

My question is about Auth.getLoggedUID function.
Assuming that I have a JWT authentication and assuming that I have an UID in payload (is that even acceptable?), what's the best option to retrieve it? Is there any, EXCEPT passing the `req` every time to every function where I need auth data?

I may have a function execution inside a function, do I need to pass the `req` through both of them to get the user ID? Like this?:

```
function getBooks(req) {
    getMyBooks(req);
    getCriminalBooks(req);
    getEvenOtherBooksByAuthor(req, authorId);
}
```

Honestly I wouldn't like that. 
Maybe my whole concept is wrong and I should be doing things differently?
Can someone point me the right direction in scenarios like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass UID in header and retrieve it inside your controller as:

```
var uid =req.header('UID');
```

Then pass this UID where ever you want there is no need to carryforward whole req object everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a middleware function. Let's say that every request that hits your endpoints, will have a token which you should check and possibly decode it. After that, you can set the decoded content to the req object. So something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // get the token from the request headers most likely.

    // verify and decode the token

    // set the decoded content to the request
    var payload = ..
    req.payload = payload;
});
```

After this you can access the payload in every single endpoint you have. So for example in some controller you can do:

```
app.get('/hey', function(req, res) {
  var payload = req.payload;
});
```